# Cross Domain Scripting

Tags: cross-domain

I am currently hosting my client side files (.html, .js) on Apache port 80. However, i want to call Jetty server port 8080 where my server side files are being hosted on. Due to the nature of my project (web-chat), the information will be required to be passed back to port 80. What is the best way to get this done? I have researched on cross-domain scripting but it failed to work.

Comment: More clarification needed to your question. Do you want to change Jetty server port number from 8080 to 80?

Comment: No, i do not want to change Jetty server port number to 80. My client side files have to be hosted on Apache port 80 whereby users access them from the browser. However, the information have to be communicated to Jetty server port 8080 whereby the server side files will be processed and passing them back to port 80, to be displayed to the user. Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Does the user client ever contact `8080` itself or is the web server the only process that will interact with Jetty?

Comment: The client side js file on port 80 will pass the information (url params etc) to 8080. Hence, i believe the web server is the only process that will interact with jetty which is transparent to the user.

Comment: I didn't realize port numbers don't qualify as cross-domain, are you sure that's your problem?

Comment: I am pretty sure cross-domain is the problem but i am guessing that i am missing something out, which i am unsure of. Tried googling for possible ways but failed to work for me. This is the error msg i received. 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.211:8080/. Origin http://192.168.1.211 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.